# Mule no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, https, mule, keystore

I have just upgraded to Mule 3.7 and getting this error. I'm using the same keystore file as I was using on 3.5. I haven't changed anything in `tls-default.conf`.

```
ERROR 2016-04-04 05:55:25,450 [[NEWSI].http.request.dispatch.8443.01 org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:292) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1035) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:738) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:221) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106) ~[commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:?]
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readLine(HttpServerConnection.java:245) ~[mule-transport-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.getRequestLine(HttpServerConnection.java:557) ~[mule-transport-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at org.mule.transport.http.HttpRequestDispatcherWork.run(HttpRequestDispatcherWork.java:67) ~[mule-transport-http-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_77]
```

This is my httpsConnector definition in mule-config.xml

```
<https:connector name="httpsConnector">
    <https:tls-client path="keystore.jks" storePassword="1234"/>
    <https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="1234" storePassword="1234"/>
    <https:tls-server path="keystore.jks" storePassword="1234"/>
</https:connector>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Which cipher suites are you expecting to be working?

Comment: Sorry, I see now that all cipher suites are enabled by default in 3.7.0 tls-default.conf. Are you using an HTTP listener or an HTTP request? Is the other part using at least TLS v1?

Comment: HTTP request. I'm not sure about your other question. Will check

Comment: Can you find out which protocols and cipher suites does the target of HTTP request allow?

Comment: How can I do that? If I use openssl to test the connection I get this `openssl s_client -connect localhost:6221` output: `CONNECTED(00000003)
16612:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:588:`

Comment: Try with this: openssl s_client -connect localhost:6221 -tls1_2

Comment: I'm getting this: `unknown option -tls1_2
usage: s_client args`. I also tried with curl and getting `curl: option --tlsv1.2: is unknown`

Comment: I don't know then, try looking at openssl documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to debug with Vm arguments. So that you can get better idea.
You can use following arguments.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

If you still not sure about what you are missing paste you host name in the following URL it will give you the which cipher suite that the host you are trying to connect is using

https://www.ssllabs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Download the [keystore explore](http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) to view your keystore.jks.

If your key is created by DSA algorithm, running Anypoint Studio on **Windows** will give you "no cipher suites in common" error which you don't see it on **Mac**

[image]

Create a new Java Key Store with RSA algorithm will get rid of this problem. Replace the old keystore with the RSA one.

[image]